# Impload a CSV file on my laptop to share point

Tags: powershell

Can someone please help me on providing a powershell script that will import my CSV file to sharepoint. I don't know what to use in order to do that.

Comment: I also tried import-CSV but it says that it couldn't find my file path, I'M 100 percent sure that my path is correct.

Comment: Add the code you are using in question if possible.

Comment: add your script, you want add this CSV to document library, or parse and add it to list?

Comment: its SharePoint Online or SharePoint On-Premises?